# How to access section headers when using UIView instead of UITableViewHeaderFooterView

Tags: ios, uitableview

When i'm using UITableViewHeaderFooterView i can access my section header with

```
MyClass *section = (MyClass *)[self.tableView headerViewForSection:0];
```

Any way to access sections if i'm using UIView as a subclass instead of UITableViewHeaderFooterView

Answer (score 2):

You could tag your custom section footer view when you create it, e.g., in `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:`, like this:

```
mySectionFooterView.tag = kMySectionFooterViewTag;
```

`kMySectionFooterViewTag` can be any `NSInteger` you like.

To access `mySectionFooterView` from some other part of your program you can then use:

```
mySectionFooterView = [myTableView viewWithTag:kMySectionFooterViewTag];
```

`myTableView` is the `UITableView` that includes your custom section footer view. You can typically access `myTableView` as `self.tableView`, when using a `UITableViewController`.

Note that there can be performance considerations with this approach, because viewWithTag: will search the entire view hierarchy of `myTableView`.

Comment: Notice that `mySectionFooterView` may be `nil` if the section footer is currently not visible. You should check what returned from `viewWithTag` to verify that you indeed got back a view.